# Why is my string input being skipped?

Tags: java, while-loop

I've been getting frustrated because my input is being skipped by the program for some reason. This causes the while loop to be skipped and the program to stop.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();

    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10.");
    int count = 1;
    int guess = input.nextInt();
        int answer = random.nextInt(1) + 1;

    while(guess != answer)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong answer. Try again.");
        guess = input.nextInt();
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("\nIt took " + count + " guesses to guess " + answer + ".");
    System.out.println("\nWould you like to play again (Y/N)?");
            String decision = input.nextLine(); // The program skips this input
            decision = decision.toUpperCase();
        while(decision.equals("Y"))
        {
    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10.");
    count = 1;
    guess = input.nextInt();
        answer = random.nextInt(1) + 1;

    while(guess != answer)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong answer. Try again.");
        guess = input.nextInt();
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("\nIt took " + count + " guesses to guess " + answer + ".");
    System.out.println("\nWould you like to play again (Y/N)?");
            decision = input.nextLine();
            decision = decision.toUpperCase();                
        }    
System.out.println("Thanks for playing.");
}
```

Comment: There's probably still a new line in the buffer from when you read it using `nextInt`

Comment: read again from the docs the difference b/w `next()` and `nextLine()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)